# How not to update all MySQL records with the same value?

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm updating MySQL records using the following SQL code, the result is always the same - it always update ALL records with the same value.

I used print_r($_POST); and found that the correct values were passed in PHP form.

```
// create and execute UPDATE query
foreach($_POST['update_category'] as $number => $update_category) {
$query = "UPDATE goals SET category='$update_category',goal='".$_POST['update_goal'][$number]."' WHERE username='$username';";
mysql_query($query, $connection);
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of SQL injection? It is a popular sport

Comment: ... Anyway `mysql_` is deprecated

Comment: Ed Heal, thank you for your concern. I will have to sanitize the input to avoid SQL injection. What is wrong with my SQL code - it's not working properly.

Comment: 1. Do not use `mysql_` library - PDO or mysqli is what to use. 2. Use prepared statements and binding.

Comment: Where does `$username` come from?

Comment: DanMan, i've a session variable that provides the value.